# Can we add another value to mongo grid fs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, grid, gridfs

I want to know if we can add additional value on mongo grid fs because the default in files are _id , filename , contenttype , length chunk and md5.

I supposed wanted to add for example file_id just an example. Supposed I can add not just filename but also like file_id.

I've tried the following code below but it only inserts the filename.

```
const fileStorage = gfs.createWriteStream({ filename: file  , file_id = id });
```

This is how I store using grid fs

```
const file = filename
const fileStorage = gfs.createWriteStream({ filename: file });
request.get(url)
    .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err) })
    .pipe(fileStorage)
    .on('close', callback);
```

This is the default values crated using mongo grid fs
including the md5 and etc.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XN1Y.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add arbitrary information into ["metadata"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#files.metadata):

```
 gfs.createWriteStream({ 
   metadata: { /*...*/ }
 })
```